# how to add check in access database using checkbox (not value of Checkbox)

Tags: c#, ms-access

with this code without adding checkbox its working properly

```
try  
{

    connection.Open();

    OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
    command.Connection = connection;
    command.CommandText = "insert into StudentInformation ([StudentID], [Lastname], [Firstname], [Middle initial], [Course], [Year], [Sem]) values ('" + txtStudentID.Text + "' , '" + txtStudentFN.Text + "','" + txtStudentFN.Text + "','" + txtStudentMI.Text + "','" + txtCourse.Text + "','" + txtYear.Text + "','" + txtSem.Text + "')";
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();

    MessageBox.Show("Added Successfully!");

    connection.Close();

}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
}
```

but when i add checkbox 
         `"insert into StudentInformain ([StudentID], ..... [Transferee] values ('" + txtStudentID.Text + "' ,...... '" + CheckBoxTrans + "')";`

i got an error
sorry for my bad english
how do i add check in my database 
(note not value of checkbox)

Comment: You really should learn ASAP how to write a parameterized query. About your error. You should put the 0 if the Checked property is false or 1 if Checked is true. Another reason to use a parameterized query

Comment: you should pass CheckBoxTrans.Checked and what is the error ?

Comment: error is data type mismatch criteria expression

Comment: help me please thanks